# Redux: Change state with input onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, recoiljs

I am using **RECOIL JS** for state management. Since recoil does not have good support for making api calls, I need to switch back to redux + thunk.

I need to update the state of my form(globally) ***while the user types***.

I used **recoil state** to achieve that:

```js
// recoil
const [s3Data, setS3Data] = useRecoilState<S3>(s3State);

const S3StateHandler = (data: string, type: TYPES) => {
    if (type === TYPES.REGION) {
      setS3Data((oldState) => ({
        ...oldState,
        [type]: data,
      }));
    } else {
      setS3Data((oldState) => ({
        ...oldState,
        params: {
          ...oldState.params,
          [type]: data.toString(),
        },
      }));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        select
        value={s3Data.region}
        onChange={(e) => S3StateHandler(e.target.value, TYPES.REGION)}
        helperText="Please select your region">
        {RegionsList.map((region) => (
          <option value={region} key={region} className={classes.selectItem}>
            {region}
          </option>
        ))}
      </TextField>
      <TextField
        value={s3Data.params.Bucket}
        onChange={(e) => S3StateHandler(e.target.value, TYPES.BUCKET_NAME)}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

I need to do the same using redux, I am unable to figure out a way to do this ***at the runtime while input changs with redux***.

Is there a way to do this? Because the only **solution** I can think of is dispatching an action on every keystroke (onChange event) which would not be optimal.

Another question is, can we make use of both? I mean, recoil for global state and redux for api calls?

Comment: When and where are the API calls made?  I'm assuming that you make a `GET` request to load the `s3State` variable?  When do you `POST` with the inputs of the form?  Also what do you mean by making the form state global?  Do other components need to access it?  Generally it's best to store form state in the component with `useState` and only put the data in Redux or another global state upon pressing "Submit".

Comment: There could be n number of child components and they all could have n number of fields. The submit button is handled by the parent component, which is way up the component tree. So I need to the values of all the child components while I hit the submit button.

Comment: Why would you use any global state management for that? The API call gets triggered by the onChange or onKeyUp event, so just trigger it there. No need to have any state management involved. For the form elements you can use `react-hook-form` which takes care of all of the stuff you need. Form values should not live in a global state.